# Refactoring of angular mat-selection-list item deletion

Tags: angular, refactoring

I'm using a `<mat-selection-list>` from the Angular Material UI Framework to add and remove options from a list.
I don't like how this is achieved in my code and wanted to ask how to do the mapping between selected items and list items for removal.


**HTML**

```html
    <div id="locationsView">
    <mat-selection-list #locations class="selectionList">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let location of locationList">
            {{location}}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>

    <div class="locationForm" id="addLocationForm" hidden=true>
        <mat-form-field class="inputField">
            <input id="newLocationInput" #newLocation matInput (keyup)="onKeyUp($event, newLocation.value)"
                placeholder="Location">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClickAddLocation(newLocation.value)" id="addLocation">
            <mat-icon id="add-icon">add_box</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="actionFooter">
    <app-actions [locationList]="locationList" [selected]="locations.selectedOptions.selected"></app-actions>
</div>
```

**TS**

The `onClickDelete()` method seems to work (as long as items are unique by their visible text, which is sufficient for my use-case), but this code makes me sad.
There must be a more precise way, using maybe indices/keys to map the selected items onto the original list...
Can someone provide a less creepy solution? maybe i missed a method on the `selectedOptions` object or maybe the angular framework foresees another way to work with dynamic lists?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actions',
  templateUrl: './actions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./actions.component.css']
})
export class ActionsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  public locationList;

  @Input()
  public selected;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClickDelete() {    
    this.selected.forEach(selectedItem => {

      this.locationList.forEach(listedItem => {

        if (selectedItem._element.nativeElement.children[0].textContent.trim() === listedItem.trim()) {          
          this.locationList.splice(this.locationList.indexOf(listedItem),1);
        }
      });

  });  

  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please consider providing more information on the *list* that you're passing as an `@Input` property? Maybe create a minimal Sample StackBlitz implementing this solution?

Comment: `locationList` is just an array of strings. nothing special there.

Comment: @Bobbey it's only "change" your variable locationList. The problem is that is an array, so you need send a "copy" of the array transformed. Some author suggest use splice() with no argument `this.locationList=this.locationList.splice(i,1).splice()`anothers use spread operator `this.locationList=[...this.LocationList.splice(i,1)]`. See that splice change the inside of the array, like push, pop... but you need make a "copy" after change the array

Comment: @Eliseo I couldn't figure this one out, apart from the datastructure not being a good choice. I just observed `selectedOptions` having private properties i could not make use of. I thought of a different, more general approach on removing items from collections by their key, which should be implemented somewhere in that `<mat-selection-list>` component.